# How to parse HTML to DOM in chrome extension

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension, that I will scan many pages of different domains in background and examine whether there are some text patterns in the pages.

I can use regex to search the plain HTML text, but I prefer to parse the HTML text into DOM and then traverse the DOM.

My question is, how can I get the DOM in a Chrome Extension ?

Thanks!

Comment: This may help: file 'htmlparser.cxx' from 'chromium source browsing'
http://code.google.com/p/chromium-source-browsing/source/browse/src/parsers/htmlparser.cxx?spec=svn.third-party--hunspell.0d7f4ca64f9288f0ce37eb8e7edba064ba400866&repo=third-party--hunspell&r=0d7f4ca64f9288f0ce37eb8e7edba064ba400866

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with jquery:

```
var html = "<html>...</html>";
var el = $(html).find(".class");
```

Comment: Ah... This just simple text search, what I need is traverse all the <a> elements in DOM and grep its 'href' attributes. Thanks!

Comment: @Yang You can do that as well, are you familiar with jquery?

Comment: Not very familiar, you mean the above code will parse HTML to DOM ? If so, can it deal with non-standard HTML ?

Comment: @Yang How non-standard, is it a valid xml? Just take a look at jquery site, there is tons of docs and examples.

Comment: @Yang Well you need to try to find out.